# Autocomplete with add more append not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, append

I am using auto complete with multiple fields using add more, for some reason its not working.

It does works for the first field but not for other fields.

Here is my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fTFkY/27/).

**JS :**

```
$(function()
{
    $('.add_more').click(function() {

        alert("ok");
        var str="";

        str +=' <div><input id=\"cities\" type=\"text\" \/><\/div>';

        $('#container').append(str);    

    });
});


$(function() {
    var states = ['Alabama', ' Alaska', ' Arizona', ' Arkansas', ' California', ' Colorado', ' Connecticut', ' Delaware', ' District Of Columbia', ' Florida', ' Georgia', ' Hawaii', ' Idaho', ' Illinois', ' Indiana', ' Iowa', ' Kansas', ' Kentucky', ' Louisiana', ' Maine', ' Maryland', ' Massachusetts', ' Michigan', ' Minnesota', ' Mississippi', ' Missouri', ' Montana', ' Nebraska', ' Nevada', ' New Hampshire', ' New Jersey', ' New Mexico', ' New York', ' North Carolina', ' North Dakota', ' Ohio', ' Oklahoma', ' Oregon', ' PALAU', ' Pennsylvania', ' PUERTO RICO', ' Rhode Island', ' South Carolina', ' South Dakota', ' Tennessee', ' Texas', ' Utah', ' Vermont', ' Virginia', ' Washington', ' West Virginia', ' Wisconsin', ' Wyoming'];
    $( "#cities" ).autocomplete({
        source: states
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_more"> Add more</a>

<div id="container">
    <div><input id="cities" type="text" /><div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Can you update my fiddle  plz ?

Comment: You should use class instead of IDs

Comment: @A.Wolff Class dont need to be dynamic like ids right ?

Comment: @CodeHunter same CLASS can be used on multiple elements  http://jsfiddle.net/fTFkY/29/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use unique `id` values for each input to wish you wish to add autocomplete.
Also, you'll need to initialize autocomplete every time an `input` element is appended.
[**Here's your updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fTFkY/28/)

```
var count = 1, states = [/* states array*/];
$(function () {
    $('.add_more').click(function () {

        alert("ok");
        var str = "";

        str += ' <div><input id=\"cities' + (++count) + '\" type=\"text\" \/><\/div>';

        $('#container').append(str);
        console.log("#cities " + count);
        $("#cities" + count).autocomplete({
            source: states
        });

    });
});





$(function () {
    $("#cities ").autocomplete({
        source: states
    });
});
```